# API call While loop not doing all lines of csv

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

While loop doesn't send all line parameters before stopping thus finishes after second pass and sometimes directly after first pass.

i have tried reducing the number of steps but plays little difference

```
import requests
import rek #request script
import time
import pandas as pd
dfbig= pd.read_csv ('C:\\Users\\libraries2.csv')



step = 19
init = 0; final = init + step
while (final<= dfbig.shape[0]):
    df = dfbig.iloc [ init : final ]
    rek.req (df , init, final) 
    init = final
    final = init + step
    time.sleep (60)
```

It just stops before completing all lines of csv

Comment: I'd say a data issue, can you send a sample of csv file.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/d30q7jDP I have pasted the data here

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incrementing `final` at the end of the loop. On the 2nd iteration `final` exceeded `dfbig.shape[0]` (ie: 19+19+19 <= 43 is false) thereby ending the loop. This has the effect of skipping over the last 5 rows.

To resolve:

```
step = 19
init = 0
final = init + step
while (init <= dfbig.shape[0]):
    df = dfbig.iloc[init:final]
    rek.req (df , init, final) 
    init = final
    final = init + step
```

Building on this [chunking idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/110772) you could do this to simplify:

```
rows = dfbig.shape[0]
for i in range(0, rows, step):
    df = dfbig.iloc[i:i + step]
    rek.req(df, i, i + step)
```